# Icefaces datatable sorting only one time

Tags: jsf-2

I am using ace:datatable to display list items from backing bean in JSF application. 
When I used sortBy its sorting only one time and display '1'(digit) when clicks sorting icons.

```
     <ace:dataTable
        id="BeanData"
        styleClass="tablestyles"
        value="#{myBean.dataList}"
        var="item"
        paginator="false"
        rendered="true"
        scrollable="true"
        scrollHeight="500"
        sortBy="#{item.id}"
        width="100%">

        ....... Some Columns.......

     </ace:datatable>
```

Can I know how to sort any number of times??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default singleSort will be false. So, you can try using singleSort="true".

```
       <ace:dataTable
    id="BeanData"
    styleClass="tablestyles"
    value="#{myBean.dataList}"
    var="item"
    paginator="false"
    rendered="true"
    scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="500"
    sortBy="#{item.id}"
    width="100%"
    singleSort = "true">

    ....... Some Columns.......

 </ace:datatable>
```

Hope this helps you!!